# Install TinyTex on a Ubuntu based Docker image: cannot verify yihui.org's certificate

Tags: tinytex

I'm trying to build a Docker image, based on [ubuntu:20.04](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/fc9c4ef6e3d4891577936f0b103331e79e1e8281/focal/Dockerfile), with R and bookdown with PDF support. But I'm getting `ERROR: cannot verify yihui.org's certificate [...]` with `tinytex::install_tinytex()`:

```
> tinytex::install_tinytex()
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.tar.gz'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.tar.gz'
--2020-11-23 09:19:05--  https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.tar.gz
Resolving yihui.org (yihui.org)... 167.99.129.42, 134.209.226.211
Connecting to yihui.org (yihui.org)|167.99.129.42|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify yihui.org's certificate, issued by 'CN=SSL-SG1-GROBU,OU=Operations,O=Cloud Services,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to yihui.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Error in download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  'wget' call had nonzero exit status
Calls: <Anonymous> ... download_file -> <Anonymous> -> download -> download.file
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.tar.gz': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
2: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.tar.gz': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
You may have to restart your system after installing TinyTeX to make sure ~/bin appears in your PATH variable (https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/16).
Execution halted
```

I need to find a way to verify and trust the certificate chain from [yihui.org](https://yihui.org/), as I'm not allowed to bypass the verification with `--no-check-certificate`.

Thanks in advance for any hint!
Mihai

Answer (score 1):

The default docker image has no certificates installed, therefore there are also no root certificates. That is what is indicated by the error message `Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority`. You can obtain the root certificates from the package `ca-certificates` (install it via `apt-get`).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29052529)

Comment: @majidhajibaba Did you check that my suggestion does not answer the question? ;)

Comment: Please explain your answer a little more to be useful for other users who have similar problems.

Comment: @majidhajibaba "please explain your answer" is not equivalent to "this is not an answer". Please be careful with your reviews.